# JavaScript form validation error not printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the following code for a form that I use to validate and want to display errors just below the fields whenever they occur:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">

.errorcss {
   background-color: yellow;
   color:red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
error=" ";

function isBlank(s) {

  var len=s.length
  var i
  for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    if(s.charAt(i) != " ") return false
  }
  return true
}

function validate(fieldName, fieldValue) {

  if(isBlank(fieldValue)) {
     error = fieldName + " cannot be left blank.";
     alert(fieldName+" cannot be left blank.")
     return false
  }
  return true
}

function validatePass(passwordValue, confirmPasswordValue) {

  if (passwordValue !== confirmPasswordValue) {
     alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")
     return false
  }
  return true
}


function validateForm() {

  if(!validate("The last name field", document.contest.last.value))
     return false
  if(!validate("The email field", document.contest.email.value))
     return false
  if(!validate("The password field", document.contest.pass.value))
     return false

  if(!validatePass(document.contest.pass.value, document.contest.repass.value))
     return false
  if(!validate("The description field", document.contest.desc.value))
     return false
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="contest" onSubmit = "return validateForm()" method="GET">
<h2 align="center">Sign Up Form</h2>
<p>
*Last Name:<input type="text" name="last" size="16">
First Name:<input type="text" name="first" size="12">
Middle Initial:<input type="text" name="initial" size="2">
</p>
<div class="errorcss">
   <script type="text/javascript">document.write(error);</script>
</div>
<p>
*E-mail Address:<input type="email" name="email">
*Password:<input type="password" size="10" name="pass">
*Confirm Password:<input type="password" size = "10" name="repass">
</p>
<p>
In 50 words or less, describe yourself:
</p>
<textarea name="desc" ROWS="5" COLS="40"></textarea>
<p>
Submit your form:<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit my form">
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is that I want the no last name error to be     displayed in the div with errorcss class. But it is not displaying it. Further I would like to know how to display all the errors whenever they occur using JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable he's asking about validation errors for the form, not JS errors.

Answer (score 2):

I added 15 semicolons, removed the script inside the error div, gave the errordiv an id ('errordiv'),  and added:

```
document.getElementById('errordiv').innerText=error;
```

in the function `validateForm();`.

**Result Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
    <style type="text/css" >

        .errorcss {
            background-color : yellow;
            color            : red;
        }
    </style >

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        error = " ";

        function isBlank( s )
        {

            var len = s.length;
            var i;
            for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
                if ( s.charAt( i ) != " " ) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function validate( fieldName, fieldValue )
        {

            if ( isBlank( fieldValue ) ) {
                error = fieldName + " cannot be left blank.";
                alert( fieldName + " cannot be left blank." );
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function validatePass( passwordValue, confirmPasswordValue )
        {

            if ( passwordValue !== confirmPasswordValue ) {
                alert( "Password and Confirm Password do not match" );
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function validateForm()
        {

            if ( !validate( "The last name field", document.contest.last.value ) ) {
                document.getElementById( 'errordiv' ).innerText = error;
                return false;
            }
            if ( !validate( "The email field", document.contest.email.value ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( !validate( "The password field", document.contest.pass.value ) ) {
                return false;
            }

            if ( !validatePass( document.contest.pass.value, document.contest.repass.value ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( !validate( "The description field", document.contest.desc.value ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script >
</head >

<body >
    <form name="contest" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET" >
        <h2 align="center" >Sign Up Form</h2 >

        <p >
            *Last Name:<input type="text" name="last" size="16" > First Name:<input type="text" name="first" size="12" > Middle Initial:<input type="text" name="initial" size="2" >
        </p >

        <div class="errorcss" id="errordiv" >

        </div >
        <p >
            *E-mail Address:<input type="email" name="email" > *Password:<input type="password" size="10" name="pass" > *Confirm Password:<input type="password" size="10" name="repass" >
        </p >

        <p >
            In 50 words or less, describe yourself:
        </p >
        <textarea name="desc" ROWS="5" COLS="40" ></textarea >

        <p >
            Submit your form:<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit my form" >
        </p >
    </form >
</body >
```

Comment: no need for semicolons as code were on different lines ... anyway thanks

Comment: yeah right, semicolons are not needed if you write javascript code on different lines :P

Answer (score 0):

There are lot many issues, one them is:

```
  <div class="errorcss">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(error);//code fails on page load
    </script>
  </div>
```

Have a look here:

```js
function isBlank(s) {
  return 0 === s.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
}

function validate(fieldName, fieldValue) {
  if (isBlank(fieldValue)) {
    alert(fieldName + " cannot be left blank.")
    return false
  }
  return true
}

function validatePass(passwordValue, confirmPasswordValue) {

  if (passwordValue !== confirmPasswordValue) {
    alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")
    return false
  }
  return true
}


function validateForm() {
  if (!validate("The last name field", document.contest.last.value))
    return false
  if (!validate("The email field", document.contest.email.value))
    return false
  if (!validate("The password field", document.contest.pass.value))
    return false

  if (!validatePass(document.contest.pass.value, document.contest.repass.value))
    return false
  if (!validate("The description field", document.contest.desc.value))
    return false
}
```

```html
<form name="contest" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">
  <h2 align="center">Sign Up Form</h2>
  *Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="last" size="16">
  <br/>First Name:
  <input type="text" name="first" size="12">
  <br/>Middle Initial:
  <input type="text" name="initial" size="2">
  <br/>*E-mail Address:
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <br/>*Password:
  <input type="password" size="10" name="pass">
  <br/>*Confirm Password:
  <input type="password" size="10" name="repass">
  <br/>In 50 words or less, describe yourself:
  <textarea name="desc" ROWS="5" COLS="40"></textarea>
  <br/>Submit your form:
  <input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit my form">
</form>
```